# Undefined variable 'csv'

Tags: python

Bearing in mind my limited understanding of coding, when I execute my code it says undefined variable 'csv' (On the bottom line). Could someone fix/explain this issue? Thanks!

```
def enterstudentdetails():
    #user is prompted to input all the required fields
    print("Enter id")
    id=input()
    print("Enter first name")
    firstname=input()
    print("Enter surname")
    surname=input()
    print("Enter Date of Birth Format: dd/mm/yy")
    dob=input()
    print("Enter first line of address")
    firstlineaddress=input()
    print("Enter Postcode")
    postcode=input()
    print("Enter Gender")
    gender=input()
    print("Enter Tutor Group")
    tutorgroup=input()
    print("Enter email address")
    email=input()
    with open('studentfile.txt','a') as studentfile:
        studentfileWriter=csv.writer(studentfile)
```

Comment: Did you import csv? `import csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you have forgot to import **csv** module: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

> If you quit from the Python interpreter and enter it again, the
>   definitions you have made (functions and variables) are lost.
>   Therefore, if you want to write a somewhat longer program, you are
>   better off using a text editor to prepare the input for the
>   interpreter and running it with that file as input instead. This is
>   known as creating a script. As your program gets longer, you may want
>   to split it into several files for easier maintenance. You may also
>   want to use a handy function that you’ve written in several programs
>   without copying its definition into each program.
>
> To support this, Python has a way to put definitions in a file and use
>   them in a script or in an interactive instance of the interpreter.
>   Such a file is called a module; definitions from a module can be
>   imported into other modules or into the main module (the collection of
>   variables that you have access to in a script executed at the top
>   level and in calculator mode).

Add at the beginning of your file:

```
import csv
```

Comment: this answer should be the verified one

Answer (score 0):

Just import csv at the beginning of your program.

```
import csv
```

Please read the documentation for csv writer to know further:-

Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

`csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`

Returns a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into delimited strings on the given file-like object. `csvfile` can be any object with a `write()` method. If `csvfile` is a file object, it must be opened with the `b` flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

An optional dialect parameter can be given which is used to define a set of parameters specific to a particular CSV dialect.

It may be an instance of a subclass of the `Dialect` class or one of the strings returned by the `list_dialects()` function.

The other optional `fmtparams` keyword arguments can be given to override individual formatting parameters in the current dialect.

Comment: Added - Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jack123 please verify this answer by clicking on tick mark of the answer. If you like my suggestion, you can also upvote. Thanks.

Comment: please @Harry_pb add more details, do not just provide the answer but also motivations of why solution is correct. this will improve a lot the quality of your answer

Comment: @saniales I hope update link will help to create motivation for further reading.